# Access XAML Instance of Class from Code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I used to have an instance of a custom class define in `app.xaml.cs` so I could access it anywhere in my application. How ever I have now changed that so that an instance of my class is made within my **Application Resources**.

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="Duplicate_Deleter.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Duplicate_Deleter">
    <Application.Resources>
        <local:runtimeObject x:Key="runtimeVariables" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**App.xaml.cs**
This is the class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace Duplicate_Deleter
    /// <summary>
    /// Global values for use during application runtime
    /// </summary>
    public class runtimeObject
    {
        //Can the application be closed?
        private bool _inProgress = false;
        public bool inProgress
        {
            get { return _inProgress; }
            set { _inProgress = value; }
        }

        //Selected folder to search in
        private string _fromFolder = "testing string";
        public string fromFolder
        {
            get { return _fromFolder; }
            set { _fromFolder = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is now, I need to be able to access this instance of the class within my code behind in my commands namespace. Below you can see one of the commands, the `App.runtime` used to work when the instance was within App.xaml.cs.

**Classes > Commands.cs**

```
public static void CloseWindow_CanExecute(object sender,
                           CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (App.runtime.inProgress == true)
            {
                e.CanExecute = false;
            }
            else
            {
                e.CanExecute = true;
            }
        }
```

How do I now reference my class instance from within my commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use TryFindResource anywhere in code:

```
public static void CloseWindow_CanExecute(object sender,
                       CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Find the resource, then cast it to a runtimeObject
        var runtime = (runtimeObject)Application.Current.TryFindResource("runtimeVariables");

        if (runtime.InProgress == true)
        {
            e.CanExecute = false;
        }
        else
        {
            e.CanExecute = true;
        }
    }
```

If the resource is not found it will return null. You could add null checking to avoid an InvalidCastException.

Comment: That's weird, i'm getting an error with "TryFindResource", error: `The name 'TryFindResource' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: Hmm that's weird, how about FindResource instead?

Comment: I figured it out - it's because you're calling it in a class outside of the main window. Use Application.Current.TryFindResource(..), updating my answer

Comment: Awesome thanks! One more related question, how would I use code behind to update a property in my XAML class instance?

Comment: You're welcome! In the code I'm showing above you are getting the object from your XAML class instance. Just use it as any other object as you wish

Comment: Ah okay, i'm assuming I need to implant INotify ect so that anything text fields binding to properties in my class will be updated right?